# Torque on an arbitrary current carrying line placed in a 2d plane due to non uniform magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, torque, integration

**Given any arbitrary current carrying Line in a plane whose shape is defined by the function y = f(x) which is kept under a non uniform magnetic field vector B now calculate the net torque about the origin on the current line due to the field . neglect any other forces.**

I am a total starter when it comes to both physics and physics exchange so apologize me if my words are not clear

I want to improvise this and need to find torque faced by current carrying surfaces and volumes to.

You can rule out the idea of it being a loop it is just a current line in a 2d plane but the main issue is that to get a good solution our function f(x) must be a one-one invertible function which rules out some interesting line figure s like y= sin(x) from [0,2π] I want a solution where non one to one functions can also be solved for.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/564284/2451

Comment: Hi jayanth kumar. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic I deleted that question my friend this is an improved version

Comment: @Qmechanic oops sorry I don't know that is the norm in the community I will follow it from now

Comment: @Qmechanic the site actually recommended me to either delete the question or to edit it

Comment: @Qmechanic how can I open this closed question

Comment: Hi jayanth kumar, unfortunately the wording is confusing, but it's out of our hands to change. We're telling you now, though: please don't repost your question, but edit it instead. I've undeleted your original question for you